# Knife Solo Cook Error

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, virtualbox, chef-solo, knife

I installed Vagrant, Virtualbox, Chef-solo and Knife in my local environment (Ubuntu 14.04). Everything was installed properly. But when I run this command "knife solo cook my.dev", it's returning an error:

```
could not extract the package.xml file from "/build/buildd/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/pear-build-download/MDB2-2.5.0b5.tgz"
Download of "pear/MDB2" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "pear/MDB2"
Download failed
install failed
```

These are the commands i did before that:

1. vagrant up
2. vagrant ssh-config --host my.dev >> ~/.ssh/config
3. knife solo cook my.dev //*Error occurs here*//
4. ssh my.dev

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess (and this is the internet so I do) something is interfering with the download of metadata from PEAR. Try installing by hand and see what the error looks like there.